# Showing a sequence does not converge to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that the sequence $$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}}$$ does not converge to $0$.

I've tried showing that it's non-decreasing and that it's bounded below by some positive value (mostly $1$, but hey), but neither method has been particularly fruitful. I'm wondering if there's really any accessible way to do this or if I should take it at face value.

For context: This is part of a larger exercise that says show (it doesn't explicitly say prove so if there's not an easily accessible proof it's not the end of the world) that the product formula $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$$ might fail to be true if the series involved to not converge absolutely by considering the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$.

Comment: For every $k$, $$(k+1)(n-k+1)\leqslant\tfrac12(n+2)^2$$ hence $$s_n\geqslant\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\sqrt2}{n+2}=\sqrt2\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

Comment: $s_n$ is an approximation to the integral $\int_0^1(x(1-x))^{-1/2}\,dx$.

Comment: @Did Perfect! Thank you! I was actually just thinking of trying something like that, too haha.

Comment: @Did Arithmetic-geometric-mean inequality even gives $\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}\le \frac{n+2}2$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True. I think I thought "$\frac14$" but was betrayed by my fingers... :-)

Comment: @Did Is that a standard inequality on the integers? I ask bc I don't recall ever seeing it before now. I'm gonna try and prove it on my own so I don't forget it-I REALLY don't want to memorize it. It looks pretty useful.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 For every real numbers $a$ and $b$, $$ab\leqslant\tfrac14(a+b)^2$$ because RHS minus LHS is $$\frac14(a-b)^2\geqslant0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
 $$\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}\leq \frac{(k+1)+(n-k+1)}{2}=\frac{n}{2}+1$$
which implies that for $n\geq 2$,
$$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}}\geq \frac{n+1}{\frac{n}{2}+1}\geq 1\implies s_n\not \to 0.$$

P.S. As remarked by Lord Shark the Unknown, the sequence $(s_n)_n$ has a limit which is
$$s_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{n}\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}}\to\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=[\arcsin(2x-1)]_0^1=\pi.$$